# Set Cursor for child control from parent window?

Tags: winapi, cursor

How can you set cursor for a child window from parent window without subclassing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WM_SETCURSOR message automatically gets passed to the parent so you can handle it there.  If the child control actually handles it then you'll have to sub-class it.  Or hack the message loop (yuck).

Answer (score 0):

```
TCHAR szButtonCoordinates[50];
RECT  rect;
switch (message)
{
...
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
     hWndButton = GetDlgItem (hWnd, IDC_BUTTON);
     GetClientRect (hWndButton, &rect);
     MapWindowPoints (hWndButton, hWnd, (LPPOINT) &rect, 2);
     // wsprintf (szButtonCoordinates, _T("Top: %d, Left: %d, Bottom: %d, Right: %d."),rect.top, rect.left,  rect.bottom, rect.right);
     if (((LOWORD (lParam) >= rect.left) && (LOWORD (lParam) <= rect.right)) && ((HIWORD (lParam) >=rect.top) && (HIWORD (lParam) <= rect.bottom)))
     {
         //MessageBox (hWndProg3, szButtonCoordinates, _T("Button Coordinates"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         SetCursor (LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_CROSS));
      }
      break; 
...
}
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Comment: above code processes WM_MOUSEMOVE message to set a different cursor over a child control window in a dialog box.